# How to do HTTP authentication in android?

Tags: android, http-authentication

I am checking out the class org.apache.http.auth.
Any more reference or example if anyone has?

Comment: Is this a question about Android applications authentication or just about authentication for a general web app, which just might run on Android?

Comment: For web authentication(http authentication) for user credentials(username,password)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I've not met that particular package before, but it says it's for client-side HTTP authentication, which I've been able to do on Android using the `java.net` APIs, like so:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("myuser","mypass".toCharArray());
    }});
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
c.setUseCaches(false);
c.connect();
```

Obviously your getPasswordAuthentication() should probably do something more intelligent than returning a constant.

If you're trying to make a request with a body (e.g. `POST`) with authentication, beware of [Android issue 4326](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4326). I've linked a suggested fix to the platform there, but there's a simple workaround if you only want Basic auth: don't bother with Authenticator, and instead do this:

```
c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +
        Base64.encode("myuser:mypass".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

Comment: Do u know any base64 encoding class present in android 2.0??

Comment: The platform has it in a few places, but oddly enough they don't expose it. They even left references to it in the docs of e.g. `android.util`. I was using `ksoap2-android` when I found this, and they have an implementation that depends only on `java.io`, so you could just grab that class (subject to its license of course) from: http://kobjects.cvs.sourceforge.net/kobjects/kobjects/src/org/kobjects/base64/Base64.java?view=markup

Comment: How do you handle the event that the authentication fails, say because the supplied credentials are bad?

Comment: Base64 is not available in older versions of Android. Any suggestions there?

Comment: i'm getting an error when trying to c.connect();   , it says IOException

Comment: @Bachask8 IOException is probably not related to authentication; I would expect a 401 Unauthorized response if authentication was bad.

Comment: The code with Authenticator is not working for me even for simple GET request.  If after c.connect() i call c.getResponseCode(), this hangs indefinitely.  My server is using digest authentication.  I m using Android api level 15.  Same works for non-android platforms.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for me. I am getting "Error response code: 301". Any idea why?

Comment: You have to use `Base64.encodeToString` in your example with `c.setRequestProperty` otherwise you're concatenating a base64 array with a string.

Answer (score 120):

For me, it worked,

```
final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("user:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Apache HttpCLient:

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

HttpUrlConnection:

```
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Comment: The NO_WRAP flag! That was key. I was just using the default and wondering why I kept getting a 400.

Comment: Your answer saves me a lot of time. Thanx! My problem was really in wrong flag (DEFAULT).

Comment: Finally, after a long time... no_wrap FTW!

Comment: wow - this NO_WRAP just ended my 5 hours problem solving against a server which had no logging... THANX!

Comment: Thanks for the nice concise answer! Android Community FTW.

Comment: Base64.encodeToString() did the trick for me. Previously, I was using Base64.encode() which was resulting in a HTTP response code of 500.

Comment: Use connection.setRequestProperty as described in other answers if you are using the HttpURLConnection class

Comment: I use this: String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s",user,passwd).getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT); and with NO_WRAP and no way to add credentials... Only get "Basic MTIzNDU2NzhBOnR0YQ==\r\n"... WHY?

Answer (score 15):

You can manually insert http header to request:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(...);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeBytes("login:password".getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 13):

Manual method works well with import android.util.Base64, but be sure to set Base64.NO_WRAP on calling encode:

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode("user:pass".getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP ));
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Answer (score 3):

For my Android projects I've used the Base64 library from here:

http://iharder.net/base64

It's a very extensive library and so far I've had no problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
 URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                            .openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +
                            Base64.encode("username:password".getBytes()));
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```