# How to authenticate with groupon?

Tags: java, android, forms-authentication, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I'm looking to develop a groupon android app that let the user look at their purchased groupon along with other stuffs. I know there's an app out there already. But it doesn't do the other stuffs I need.

Anyways, I'm struggle on authentication?  How do I take the same idea from web browser and allow my app to login with user credential and pull various information?  Groupon has the API. But it seems to be specific to a client key (ie. Look at your own stuffs only)

If someone can point me to some directions, or if you wrote similar codes and could share, I would really appreciate it. I'm looking to the same authentication with living social as well.

Thank you for your time

Jack

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/) of how to access a web-service using Android's api's.

[Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android) shouldn't be especially [difficult](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app).