# Android HTTP Authentication 

Tags: android, authentication, http-authentication

How do I authenticate via HTTP in Android?

Comment: Yes I know, but i just intend to share my findings so that it could help other :)

Comment: Please at least clean up your code (`TODO Auto-generated method stub`, `System.err`, `rohit`?), format it nicely, **post it as an answer** to your own question and then accept it.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed if Rohit will follow the advice from @Philipp.

Comment: Is this a dupe of this: [How to do HTTP authentication in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android)

Comment: Please, just edit your question if you wan to add additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I face very much dificuly to authenticate via HTTP in Android as in browser (web and Android native) it worked perfect and ask for credentials but this scene is not in code. so here is the code I used.

```
URL url = new URL("YOUR URL HERE");


Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
          @Override
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                 System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
                 return (new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray()));
          }});
InputStream stream = url.openStream();
```

Comment: If this really is an answer to your question, you should accept it as such.