# How to restrict access to images on server, except via mobile devices?

Tags: php, android

I am building a simple android app for viewing images located in public_html/preciousImages which is password-protected folder on a hosted server.

I understand that I'll need to use HTTP authentication for providing user/pass ([Android HTTP Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288526/android-http-authentication) ), however, these credentials, when embedded in code, can be easily hacked using debugging apps like Charles; and then used to leech/hot-link the images.

So I want to implement another layer of security and looking for a way to allow access to the images only from mobile devices (android for now; iOS and android in the future).

Is this the right line of thinking? Or is there a better way to do it (server settings, php, anything...)? I am not worried about compromising small number of images (downloading one-by-one on mobile device) but would really like to avoid them being leeched en-mass.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate request for the images in post body and by setting some custom header for that like

```
// Http Post Header
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpPost.setHeader("IsFromApp", "true");
```

Here **`httpPost.setHeader("IsFromApp", "true");`** may differentiate the request from others. We can judge on server side that the header which is true for `IsFromApp` then request is from mobile device or Android Device. You can customize that accordingly.

**Happy Coding**

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I understand that the header can still be compromised using Charles (or can't it ??) and an attacker may use it to initiate a request from any device, however, this should be enough to thwart the noob attackers.

Answer (score 0):

go for public key, private encription using hmac sha1. Android has native libraries for it.

check this  [QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6026339/793943)

Comment: Being a novice, this solution seems a bit intimidating to me and I am looking to go with @Varuns 's idea for now, however, I'd definitely like to implement this or a similar mechanism in near future. Thanks

Comment: ok. i misstaken u, i tot u want protect images sent from mobile.