# How to connect android application to CakePhp to exchange data

Tags: android, database, cakephp, authentication

### Heading

I want create an application for an already created website(in cakephp),

I want to login from my app to the CakePhp database, how can I do this?

Also i want to fetch some user information from the website to my app
please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the user, a website built with CakePHP is identical to one built without. CakePHP simply makes the build process easier. So, that said, if you want to access information using a browser in Android you need to make a logon page or API.

There really isn't a specific way to target android only. If you want to connect to a site (authenticate perhaps?) then look at questions like this one: [How to do HTTP authentication in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android) or do some google searching and come back with a more specific question