# Android Volley ignoring params can't connect

Tags: java, android, http-headers, httprequest, android-volley

I'm  trying to connect to a local API using volley, I passed all the required parameters but it's not working, if I get rid of the email and password and let only the token request it works, so the problem is in the email and password, but those parameters are being ignored, how can I get it working?

```
package quest.testvolley;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.kpbird.volleytest.R;



        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.android.volley.Request;
        import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        String url = "http://192.168.1.1/represente-mais-api/api/clientes";

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", "rm@sss.com.br");
        params.put("senha", "sss");
        //params.put("X-API-TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkD0afd19MfacGa3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");




        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                txtDisplay.setText("Response => "+response.toString());
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {



                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d( "Error: " + error.getMessage());


                }
            })



        {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    headers.put("X-API-TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkD0bDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");

                    return headers;
                }



        };
        queue.add(req);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: change GET to  Request.Method.Post

Comment: Unexpected response code 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are specifying the HTTP Request type as GET, yet adding form data
>   to it.
>
> ```
>     JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, ...
> ```
>
> You want to be doing an HTTP Post method. Therefore you should replace
>   Request.Method.GET to Request.Method.POST to post FormData to the
>   server.
>
> More about HTTP Methods [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

EDIT: If you are getting a 401 while trying an HTACCESS see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android). You need to pass the parameters using an Authenticator.

Comment: I already tried that, still getting Unexpected response code 401

Comment: 401 is the status code for "unauthorized". That means that you do not have sufficient permissions to access this url. What code is running @ http://192.168.1.1/represente-mais-api/api/clientes ?