# The headers is too long in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load my token auth into the header of a WebView on Android API18, when I make the call it says HTTP ERROR 400. The size of the request headers is too long

```
 Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
 extraHeaders.put("Authorization","Bearer - " + token);
 host.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
```

Any ideas how to override this if possible, as I want to pass the token in the authorize header?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9377571/2197087

Answer (score 0):

Thank you will try using the HTTP client with the WebView, I have used it when making a Web Api request.