# android volley https response code 400 for api 10

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using volley library and overriding getHeaders() method to put custom headers. It is working fine for devices with API > 10 but for devices with API 10 it returns unexpected response code 400.

The headers in https are the same for devices with API 17 and API 10. I have also updated the volley lib to newest version, but with no luck.

In getHeaders() method I'm putting

```
String encodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
headerMap.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
```

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have found the problem. For android API 10 the headers from https request were cut off. The only header was Authorization that was added manually.

I have changed Base64.DEFAULT to Base64.NO_WRAP and it is working now. I have found the answere here:

[How to do HTTP authentication in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android)